# What exactly is a CRUD table

Tags: java, database, crud

What is a CRUD table and what is it used for? Is this just another name for a hash table?

I know that CRUD stands for create, retrieve, update, and delete. Are these not just the functions of a regular DB table?

Could someone give an example, maybe in Java?

Comment: I've never heard the term "CRUD table". Where are you getting it from?

Comment: I found it on a site and remember it being asked in an interview question: http://quizlet.com/11519596/java-interview-review-flash-cards/

Comment: There is CRUD on that site but not next to a table?

Answer (score 4):

There is no CRUD table. CRUD refers to operations on a table: create, retrieve, update, and delete. Those operations can be executed on any table. They are bundled together as they are the most basic operations.

Answer (score 1):

A large number of applications that people write are 'crud'.  They are simply creating entries in a database, reading them, updating them, and deleting them.  Managing users, bug tracking, retail stock inventories... all mostly CRUD with various business logic wrapped around it from time to time.

There isn't such a thing as a crud *table*.  Its just the most common type of application you will find out there, and a good bet what most programmers find themselves writing time and time again.

That the name [crud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crud) is synonymous with 'dirt, filth, or waste, or something of poor quality' shows part of the distain that many people have for writing such applications.  On this theme, some people will jokingly refer to "Create, Retrieve, Alter, Purge" as another form of the application.